# Update in oracle with joining two table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have these two tables below, I need to update `Table1.Active_flag` to `Y`, where `Table2.Reprocess_Flag` is `N`.

Table1

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Source | Subject_area | Source_table | Target_table | Active_flag |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| a      | CUSTOMER     | ADS_SALES    | ADS_SALES    | N           |
| b      | CUSTOMER     | ADS_PROD     | ADS_PROD     | N           |
| CDW    | SALES        | CD_SALES     | CD_SALES     | N           |
| c      | PRODUCT      | PD_PRODUCT   | PD_PRODUCT   | N           |
| d      | PRODUCT      | PD_PD1       | PD_PD1       | N           |
| e      | ad           | IR_PLNK      | IR_PLNK      | N           |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Table2

```
| Source | Subject_area | Source_table | Target_table | Reprocess_Flag |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| a      | CUSTOMER     | ADS_SALES    | ADS_SALES    | N              |
| b      | CUSTOMER     | ADS_PROD     | ADS_PROD     | N              |
| CDW    | SALES        | CD_SALES     | CD_SALES     | N              |
| c      | PRODUCT      | PD_PRODUCT   | PD_PRODUCT   | Y              |
| d      | PRODUCT      | PD_PD1       | PD_PD1       | Y              |
| e      | ad           | IR_PLNK      | IR_PLNK      | N              |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Your question is not readable.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post your code please

Comment: UPDATE hdfs_cntrl
SET active_flag = 'Y'
where source in ( select source from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N')
and subject_area in (select subject_area from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N')
and source_table in (select target_table from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N');

Comment: Please add your code to the question, do not add comments; also, what is the problem with this code? are you having an error (which?) or an unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Use all three columns in a single select statement.

```
UPDATE hdfs_cntrl SET active_flag = 'Y' 
where (source,subject_area ,source_table ) in  ( select source,subject_area ,source_table from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N');
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating one table based on data in another table is almost always best done with the MERGE statement.

Assuming `source` is a unique key in `table2`:

```
merge into table1 t1
  using table2 t2
  on (t1.source = t2.source)
when matched
  then update set t1.active_flag = 'Y'
  where t2.reprocess_flag = 'N'
;
```

If you are not familiar with the MERGE statement, read about it - it's just as easy to learn as UPDATE and INSERT and DELETE, it can do all three types of operations in a single statement, it is much more flexible and, in some cases, more efficient (faster).

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into table1 t1
using table2 t2
on (t1.sorce=t2.source and t1.Subject_area = t2.Subject_area and t1.Source_table = t2.Source_table and t1.Target_table = t2.Target_table and t2.flag_status = 'N')
when matched then update set
t1.flag = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE hdfs_cntrl SET active_flag = 'Y' where source in ( select source from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N') and subject_area in (select subject_area from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N') and source_table in (select target_table from proc_cntrl where Reprocess_Flag = 'N')